# Speech recognition at MAC and PC

Tags: wpf, winforms, macos, speech-recognition

I have to make speech recogintion application that should work on MAC and PC, i have a idea about SAPI but it will for only for PC not for MAC.

Is there any other API or frame work i can use to achieve this, programing language not bar for me.

Comment: Programming language not bar for me? So you don't care if it's C, Assembly, PHP, ASP or maybe even JavaScript? Do you write all languages or what?

Comment: -_- http://www.pcmag.com/article2/0,2817,2327233,00.asp

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft offers a [Speech recognition SDK.](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=5e86ec97-40a7-453f-b0ee-6583171b4530&displaylang=en). Then you can use directions like [these](http://mac.sillydog.org/dev/visual_studio.php) that show how to program VS for OS X.

Answer (score 0):

Apple offers a speech recognition API [NSSpeechRecognizer](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSSpeechRecognizer%5FClass/index.html)